Webkit scrollbar responding to mouse but not touch?
I am puzzled as to why the webkit-scrollbar works just fine with a mouse but not at all with a touch event. Experienced in Chrome.
I have a div "container" with overflow-y: auto. When the scrollbar appears, I can click on the scrollbar thumb with the mouse and scroll up and down just fine. However, when I use touch to try and move it nothing happens. I have tried resizing the scrollbar thumb, setting touch-action: pan-y;, altering the contents/styling of the div but nothing works. I cant find anything else online where a similar problem is experienced. Looking in the MDN docs touch is implemented for scrollbars and should be working. Not sure what could be causing this inconsistency.
.container {
height: 5rem;
overflow-y: auto;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 1.25rem;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: red;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  width:1.25rem;
}

<div class="container">
   <ul>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>


Non standard element not supported in all browsers, use scrollbar-width instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Unfortunately this does not resolve the unresponsiveness to touch issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Have you actually tried actually giving them a pixel width instead of relative units?
